# React - How to pass clases and inline styles as props in

Tags: css, reactjs, styles

I used to have this and it worked fine:

```
<div className="right mr3 relative center" style={{ marginTop: -300, zIndex: 2 }}>
```

Now I need to pass that entire class and inline style as props,

```
tooltipClassName={"right mr3 relative center" style={{ marginTop: -300, zIndex: 2 }}}
```

And then call that class like this `<div className={tooltipClassName}>`

Maybe I need to use string interpolation or pass another prop as styles but I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class & style are different HTML attributes, so string interpolation won't really work here. One option:

```
<SomeComponent tooltipClasses={'right mr3 relative center'} tooltipStyles={{ marginTop: -300, zIndex: 2 }} />

// inside of SomeComponent render:
<div className={this.props.tooltipClasses} style={this.props.tooltipStyles}>
```

Alternately you could write your own class with the z-index and margin values and add that class to the array

Comment: This works with inline style or css class name, but how to pass when style is defined scss file?